# Passing arguments/flags to `build.rs`

Tags: rust

Is there an accepted way of threading through to [Rust's `build.rs` build scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) some sort of flag that could be specified at `cargo build`?

Just to be clear, I realize that having custom flags to `cargo build` sounds like a generally bad idea (for instance, what flags are passed to dependencies?). My use case is mostly to support unusual debugging workflows for other people working on this project. For instance,

- specifying a custom include path
- indicating that a C/C++ library should be built from scratch (instead of just linking to an already installed version)

Am I better off just passing this sort of information via an environment variable?

Comment: Environment variables are the usual way AFAIK. Why would you not want to use them?

Comment: Cool thanks! Just checking in case I missed something. :)